# No digits Java Regex Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I want a regex pattern to check that the string doesn't contain any digits .

For Illustration : 
I'm coding a Hospital System and I want from user to enter the name of the patient , Of course the name shouldn't contain any digits , how can I do this by Regex ?

Comment: Unless, of course, it's legal to have a name that includes digits. I've seen some odd names over the years.

Comment: jball: SQL doesn't relate to this question. Also I think checking just for digits with regex is a bit of an overkill, certainly if you expect a certain form for the name then it's alright but I'm willing to bet that using any of the helper methods in `Character` class itself is faster than any regex.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`\D` is a non-digit, and so then `\D*` is any number of non-digits in a row. So your whole string should match `\D*`.

Comment: That regex is fine if you're using the `matches()` method.  If you use `find()` you'll always get a match, digits or no.  If for some reason you had to use `find()` you would need to anchor the regex: `^\D*$`

Answer (score 3):

\A\D*\Z

a good regex [cheatsheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/) here

Answer (score 2):

Try: \D

See the JavaDoc for [Pattern](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well names usually alphabetical, so this will be good : `[a-b,A-Z, ,-]+`

EDIT : `[a-zA-Z- ',]+`

Comment: what about names that include an apostrophe?

Comment: Why do you have all those commas in there?  All they do is match a literal comma in the target string.  And what's with the range `a-b`?  Isn't that supposed to be `a-z`?

Comment: ASCII is not the only *charset*; what about names with 'ç', 'ã', 'ä', 'à', 'œ',...